# Coloring code disappeared

Tags: eclipse, colors

Today I opened Eclipse Helios, and wanted to do some job. But when it opened I saw that there is no highlighted code, just class field are blue. I don't remember that I was changing configuration. How to set this to default?
Here is screenshot:
[image]

Now keywords like public, void, throws are just black and bold.

Comment: did u try restore defaults under window-> Preferences?

Comment: @Babu, you are right, it works. I tried to set default on Editor and Code Highlight, but forgot to restore defaults on whole preferences. Write answer to accept as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try **restore defaults** under window-> Preferences.

[image]